# Using NotificationListener and NestedScrollView is giving unexpected scroll behaviour in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver, nestedscrollview, sliverappbar

I'm using `CustomSliverDelegate` and `CustomNestedScrollView`. When i scroll up from the bottom of the screen, the scroll behaviour is working perfectly fine.After scrolling up, i tried to scroll down from the middle of the screen or just above from the bottom of the screen, the `SliverGrid` is automatically scrolling all the way to the top of the `SliverGrid`. I want to remove this behaviour. But when i scroll down from the bottom part of the screen, the scroll behaviour is working perfectly fine. I'm testing this on real device.

[Here's the scroll behaviour video](https://imgur.com/a/yUacN9K)

right click on the video and open in new tab for better view.

[Take a look at this GIF (Telegram gif)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64726368/automatic-expand-collapse-sliverappbar)

That is the scroll behaviour that i want to achieve.

code is below.

custom_nested_scroll_view.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../../widgets/common/custom_sliver_delegate.dart';

class CustomNestedScrollView extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget widget;
  final String appbarName;
  final Widget sliverCard;

  CustomNestedScrollView({
    super.key,
    required this.widget,
    required this.appbarName,
    required this.sliverCard,
  });

  final _controller = ScrollController();

  bool _scrollNotificationHandler(scrollNotification) {
    if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification &&
        scrollNotification.depth == 0) {
      final minExtent = scrollNotification.metrics.minScrollExtent;
      final maxExtent = scrollNotification.metrics.maxScrollExtent;
      final middle = (maxExtent - minExtent) / 2;
      final pos = scrollNotification.metrics.pixels;

      double? scrollTo;

      if (minExtent < pos && pos <= middle) {
        scrollTo = minExtent;
      } else if (middle < pos && pos < maxExtent) {
        scrollTo = maxExtent;
      } else {
        scrollTo = null;
      }

      if (scrollTo != null) {
        Timer(
          const Duration(milliseconds: 1),
          () => _controller.animateTo(scrollTo ?? 0.0,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease),
        );
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: _scrollNotificationHandler,
      child: NestedScrollView(
        controller: _controller,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverOverlapAbsorber(
              handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
              sliver: SliverPersistentHeader(
                pinned: true,
                delegate: CustomSliverDelegate(
                  sliverCard: sliverCard,
                  appbarName: appbarName,
                  expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4.5,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: SafeArea(
          top: false,
          child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return CustomScrollView(
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverOverlapInjector(
                  // This is the flip side of the SliverOverlapAbsorber above.
                  handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                    context,
                  ),
                ),
                // const SliverToBoxAdapter(
                //   child: SizedBox(
                //     height: 10,
                //   ),
                // ),
                widget,
              ],
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

custom_sliver_delegate.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../utils/colors.dart';

class CustomSliverDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final String appbarName;
  final Widget sliverCard;
  final double expandedHeight;
  final bool hideTitleWhenExpanded;

  CustomSliverDelegate({
    required this.expandedHeight,
    required this.appbarName,
    required this.sliverCard,
    this.hideTitleWhenExpanded = true,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    final appBarSize = expandedHeight - shrinkOffset;
    final cardTopPosition = expandedHeight / 2 - shrinkOffset;
    final proportion = 2 - (expandedHeight / appBarSize);
    final percent = proportion < 0 || proportion > 1 ? 0.0 : proportion;
    return SizedBox(
      height: expandedHeight + expandedHeight / 1,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: appBarSize < kToolbarHeight
                ? kToolbarHeight + 40
                : appBarSize + 40,
            child: AppBar(
              iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                color: cardTopPosition <= 0 ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
              ),
              backgroundColor:
                  cardTopPosition <= 0 ? Colors.white : AppColors.primaryColor,
              elevation: 0.0,
              title: Opacity(
                opacity: hideTitleWhenExpanded ? 1.0 - percent : 1.0,
                child: Text(
                  appbarName,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          cardTopPosition <= 0
              ? const SizedBox.shrink()
              : Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 150,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Opacity(
                      opacity: percent,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8 * percent),
                        child: Card(
                          surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                            child: sliverCard,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => expandedHeight + expandedHeight / 2;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 100;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

grid_view_screen.dart

```
class GridViewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const GridViewScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<GridViewScreen> createState() =>
      _GridViewScreenState();
}

class _GridViewScreenState extends State<GridViewScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    context.read<GridDataBloc>().add(GridDataLoadEvent());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => context.push("/add"),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: CustomNestedScrollView(
        sliverCard: const AppBarCard(),
        appbarName: "Product categories",
        widget: BlocConsumer<GridDataBloc, GridDataBlocState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is GridDataErrorState) {
              showSnackBar("Something went wrong! please try again.");
            }
          },
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is GridDataLoadingState) {
              return const SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              );
            } else if (state is GridDataLoadedState) {
              final categories = state.productCategories;
              return GridDataCards(categories: categories); // SliverGrid Widget
            } else {
              return const SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the main problem is in this if condition ( if (minExtent < pos && pos <= middle) )  and the else if condition ( else if (middle < pos && pos < maxExtent) ) which is in the _scrollNotificationHandler function of custom_nested_scroll_view.dart. Can anyone help me?